# meta charset for unicode

Tags: html, unicode, utf-8

I am using Jekyll which has [**some issues**](http://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/issues/188) with UTF-8 files. I was able to work around this by saving the file as Unicode (UTF-16 LE).

However it is an HTML document, which until now I have been using the

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

line in the file. Is this charset still correct or should I be using another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some
[**information**](http://w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations) from the World Wide Web Consortium.

```
HTML5 with UTF-16
Ensure that there is a byte-order mark 
at the beginning of the file. 

The HTML Working Group is currently discussing whether 
you can use a meta element declaration in the head 
element when the encoding is UTF-16. For now, don't.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you save the file as UTF-16 LE, you have to update the `<meta>` tag to match.

Answer (score 0):

The document cited deals with “incorrect UTF-8 characters”, whatever that means. Just don’t do incorrect UTF-8 characters.

Saving an HTML file as UTF-16 is normally pointless, because UTF-16 just does not work on the web. Of course the `meta` tag should describe the real encoding, but that’s not the point, and charset declaration in HTTP headers will override any `meta` tags.

So keep using UTF-8, and fix the problem with your character data, instead of creating a new, serious problem.